# Not getting any output from mathematica script

Tags: output, scripting, command-line

I am completely new, so this question may be trivial, but I can't find any answers in the Wolfram documentation.

I am playing around with scripting in Mathematica, but I cannot seem to get any type of output when I run my basic script `test_script.wl`:

```
#!/usr/local/env MathematicaScript -script
Print["Hello World!"]
```

I then run it from the windows command prompt like so:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Wolfram Research/Mathematica\11.3\wolfram" -script test_script.wl
```

But to no avail. "Hello World!" is not printed.

I have tried using `wolframscript` as well, and the results are the same.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm running Mathematica 11.3 on Windows 10, 64 bit.